# Why does PhpStorm block certain keypresses on certain filetypes?

Tags: editor, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 8.0.2.  On certain file types like .html the editor limits what I can type. For example, pressing **Enter** does nothing inside any of the tags (if I want a new space, I need to type **Shift-Enter**.

This happens even with a stub text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say I'm on the line with the **body** tag, and hit **Enter**. Nothing happens. Similarly, if I try to close a **div** with a '>', the editor won't let me, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"
</body>
</html>
```

I've disabled all third party plugins, and sifted through the editor settings to see if some auto-formatting settings would be responsible, but I haven't found anything applicable. I've tried to delete the .idea folder in the project root in case the project files would've somehow become corrupted (made no difference), and also tried to turn off HTML inspections (made no difference).

It's also interesting to note that the editor does let me add '<' and '>' characters when they're not associated with any tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<<><<><><<<>>><<><
</body>
</html>
```

This suggests that specific keypresses are indeed limited by some kind of context-awareness that is not working as expected.

Any thoughs on this? I've observed this on earlier versions of PhpStorm as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Screenshots please (using default color scheme).

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log. But try invalidating caches first (File/Invalidate caches, restart). I can recall similar problems when working with Angular.. Invalidating caches helped

Comment: @lena Thanks for that tip; invalidating the caches did the trick! :)

(If you make this an actual answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it as the correct answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try invalidating caches(File/Invalidate caches, Restart). Such issues can be caused by broken indexes